# VBA: Application.Run won't return changed variable

Tags: excel, vba

CODE:

```
Option Explicit

Sub aaa()
  Dim zQ0z
  zQ0z = "1st String"

  'Call bbb(zQ0z) '<------------------------- Call (commented)
  Application.Run "bbb", zQ0z

  MsgBox zQ0z '<------------------------- 2nd MsgBox
End Sub

Sub bbb(zQ0z)
  zQ0z = "2nd String"

  MsgBox zQ0z '<------------------------- 1st MsgBox
End Sub
```

The results are following:

| Calling method | 1st MsgBox | 2nd MsgBox |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Call (as if not commented) | `2nd String` | `2nd String` |
| Application.Run | `2nd String` | `1st String` (in question) |

So, it seems that Application.Run works the same way as if the variable had been passed "ByVal" - saving no changes it undergoes in a Run'ing procedure (no matter how `bbb` recieves it).

Is there a way to get `2nd String` in a 2nd MsgBox via Application.Run?

Comment: Might be that `Application.Run` runs it as a separate process. Processes don't return variables.

Comment: Arguments to Application.Run are passed by value.   http://tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1022_ByRef_Argument_with_the_Application_Run_method.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `Run` then make `bbb` a function which returns the value you want.

```vb
Sub aaa()

    Dim zQ0z
    zQ0z = "1st String"

    zQ0z = Application.Run("bbb", zQ0z)

    MsgBox zQ0z ' "2nd string"
End Sub

Function bbb(zQ0z)
        bbb = "2nd String"
End Function
```

Comment: Omg. Thank you ><

Comment: Functions will solve a problem for only 1 variable tho; `zQ0z` in our case (via `zQ0z = App.Run("bbb")`). That's a bummer.

Comment: You can return a Type, an instance of a class, or an array if you need to return multiple items.